# Selected date is not showing in datepicker in angular.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, datepicker

I am working on an MVC 5 project with Angular js. I am using a date picker control.

In my webpage using `directive` in `app.js`.

```
myApp.directive('datepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ProfileCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            //dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
            dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                ProfileCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                //ProfileCtrl.$render();
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Everything works fine, but there is a problem when I select a date. It shows the selected date in date picker. For example selected date is June 1 2015

[image]

I am save this value on database. I populate the date picker again, but selected date is not selected in date picker.

[image]

My system date format is `dd-MM-yyyy`.

**Edit :**

Please see my **html code** below.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
     .........
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dob" class="col-md-2 control-label">DOB</label>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" datepicker name="dob" class="form-control" ng-model="models.DOB" />

        </div>

    </div>
```

**Angular Controller code**

```
$http.get("Profile/GetProfile").success(function (data) {

    $scope.models = {
        Name: data.Name,
        UserEmail: data.UserEmail,
        Password: data.Password,
        ConfirmPassword: data.ConfirmPassword,
        DOB: data.DOB,
        Address: data.Address,
        City: data.City,
        Country: data.Country,
        Pincode: data.Pincode,
        Phone: data.Phone

    }

});
```

**C# controller**

```
    public ActionResult GetProfile()
    {

        string _CustomerId = CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieHelper.EndUser.UserId);
        long CustomerId = 0;

        if (!Int64.TryParse(_CustomerId, out CustomerId))
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        Customer customer = CustomerHelper.GetCustomer(CustomerId);

        if (customer == null)
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        var data = new
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name,
            UserEmail = customer.Email,
            Password = customer.Password,
            ConfirmPassword = customer.Password,
            DOB = (customer.DOB != new DateTime?()) ? ((DateTime)customer.DOB).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : string.Empty,
            Address = customer.Address,
            City = customer.City,
            Country = customer.Country,
            Pincode = customer.Pincode,
            Phone = customer.Phone
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If DOB field is contain a date value the date picker is not show that date in blue color, and date format is different in page load and date changed event.

Comment: Does saving to the database matter in this scenario? If it does, could you post the code for that? Also, you say 'populate' the datepicker again. Why don't you use the same datepicker from before which would remember its model? Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Does this view reload after you save data to database?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. @azium there is no problem in saving section. It's works fine. and there is no page refreshing happend after save method. But if a date value in the DOB field the date picker is not show that date in blue color. and the date format is different in page load and after the date selection.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. @Rebornix there is no reloading after the saving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use momentjs to manipulate the date format to suit the datepicker field. Check out it here http://momentjs.com/ .Your server side and client date formats might be different.